# Do you "count" the dataset size in number of images or number of ground truth bounding boxes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm currently making a custom dataset with 1 class. The images i am labeling contains several of these objects in each image (between 30-70). I therefore wonder if I should count each of the objects in each image as "1 datapoint" when evaluating the size of the dataset?

I.e: Does more objects per image require less images?

Comment: Does the 1 class correspond to the whole image or the single objects?

Comment: 1 class corresponds to the single objects in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being this a detection problem, the size of the dataset is given both by the number of images and the number of objects. There is no reason to choose one of the two because they are both equally important numbers.
If you really want to define "size" you probably have to start from the error metric. Usually for object detection mIoU (Mean Intersection over Union) is used. This metric is at the object level so it doesn't care if you have 10 or 1 million images.

Finally, it could be that having many objects per image will allow you to use a smaller number of total images, but this can only be confirmed experimentally.